# How do I get my macro to run automatically every Tuesday at 1:20pm?

Tags: excel, vba

I have a macro called DCS and I am trying to get it to run automatically every Tuesday. How do I achieve this?

Comment: Is the workbook going to be open at such time?

Comment: It is not open but the first line of the code opens a txt file.

Comment: The macro is in my personal macro workbook. It is not attached to a specific workbook.